# sway/i3: How to make one of two different VM-Windows sticky on all Workspaces in sway?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, sway

On my debian with sway I have two different virtual machines (VM1 + VM2). The virtual machines are running with qemu-kvm and virt-viewer. I want to make the virt-viewer-window of VM1 sticky in all Workspaces of sway, as described [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_sticky_floating_windows).

When I add to `~/.config/sway/config-file` the lines

```
# make the virt-viewer-window of VM1 sticky
for_window [app_id=virt-viewer] sticky enable
```

*both* VM-windows get sticky. But I just want to make one of the two VM-windows sticky. How can I achieve my goal? Do I have to use the ID of the VM that I want to make sticky? What must it look like in the configuration file above?